# Scrolling back to last position on site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My site uses this javascript function to scroll to anchors on the page;

```
        function scrollToAnchor(aid){
            var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
        }
```

This does as intended,

```
        $( window ).ready(function() {
            <?php 
                if (isset($_GET['track'])) {
                    echo 'scrollToAnchor("viewTrack");';
                }
            ?>
        });
```

I integrated a jQuery function in with PHP, not sure if that is okay to do but it seems to work.

My problem. When the page is loading it scrolls to where i need it to, but then it snaps back to the last known scrolling position of the site once everything has loaded. How can i prevent this?

Comment: You should add `preventDefault()` to the `scrollToAnchor` function

Comment: I think you need to change `window` to `document`. Then the `scrollToAnchor` will run when the document is loaded

Comment: Yeah i tried document, it had no effect. I shall try `preventDefault()`

Comment: `preventDefault()` worked, thank you.